# FMA and LMO communication for 2gp

Tags: 2gp, fma, lmo

I have created a 2gp package for FMA which works perfectly when using feature parameters in an unmanaged deployment context.

My request is the following: interact to the subscribers while being the LMO (I have partner PBO in trial)

My assumption/question is: is this only possible after the package is installed only after successfully passed security review and installed through app exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak to how to works with 1gp but I would imagine it is the same. If it's not please correct me.

You will need to pass the security review first. Once that is done, then the package  will be installed into the subscribers org. Once that is completed you can set the feature parameter (which is related to the license).

The exact related list will depend on the type of feature parameter. It will look something like this.

[image]